# Cordova ios app build error shows - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, cordova

[Error while archiving ios app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHoQp.png)

I am archiving cordova iOS app in xcode and getting

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Whrn I use simple build option it works fine, but when i choose "Product>Destination>Generic iOS Device" and then "Product>Archive". It gives this error

Comment: Are you using Xcode 10 beta 5?
there is a bug in Xcode beta 5 that prevents building. if this, then update to beta 6 and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: yes i am using Xcode beta 5.

Comment: Thank you @AliMoazenzadeh it worked